# How to make loading screen run until all image are loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i try to make a loading screen while waiting for all images are fully loaded.
React Lifecycle is Render -> componentDidMount -> render, my images are not fully loaded, just got called but my `componentDidMount` always finishes and executes render even my image isn't fully loaded.

```
componentDidMount() {
            const ie = [document.querySelectorAll('img')];
            ie.map(imgElm => {
                for (const img of imgElm) {
                    if (!img.complete) {
                        this.setState({ imageIsReady : true});
                    }
                }
                return this.setState({ imageIsReady : false});
            })
    }
```

on the `componentDidMount` for loop function try to check every img is complete or not, give me a hundred `true` (my image is a lot, just try to make gallery). and loading screen shows but only a few ms, then I can scroll over my image but more than half of my image is still loading.

```
render() {
<div>
 {
  this.state.imageIsReady ?
    <div className='inset-0 fixed flex justify-center z-20 w-full h-full bg-black bg-opacity-25 blur'>
      <img src={loading} className='w-3/12' alt="load"/>
    </div> :
    <div className='hidden '>
      <img src={loading} alt="load"/>
    </div>
  }
   <div>page......</div>
</div>
}
```

my code: https://alfianahar.github.io/MobileLegendHeroList/ in this site I use `setTimeout` on my `componentDidMount`, this does not solve my problem when using slow 3g nor fast 3g/

Comment: Why are you enclosing with `[]` in `const ie = [document.querySelectorAll('img')];`?

Comment: @ShivamJha because if i did not enclose using `[ ]`, the map become not function (ie become array if I put `[ ]`), I tried to delete this before and `TypeError: ie.map is not a function` show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example can help you. But remember that will works only for image which aren't nested inside components.

```js
class Component extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          ready: false
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
      Promise.all(
          Array.from(document.images)
              .filter(img => !img.complete)
              .map(img => new Promise(
                  resolve => { img.onload = img.onerror = resolve; }
              ))).then(() => {
                  this.setState({ ready: true })
              });
  }


  render() {
      if ( ! this.state.ready ) return <div>Loader</div>

      return <div>Content</div>
  }
}
```

```
<Container>
    <img/> <!-- work -->
    <Component>
        <img/> <!-- doesn't work -->
    </Component>
</Container>
```

Comment: Omg, i use arrayfrom. document.images before... then map, then onload. I didn't think of using `filter` before.. thanks, bro u save my day..... Simpliest solution that I got...

Answer (score 0):

React `16.8.x`

```js
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const [imagesRequested, setImagesRequested] = React.useState({});
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([
    { name: "first image", src: "https://picsum.photos/200/300" },
    { name: "second image", src: "https://picsum.photos/300/300" }
  ]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {images.map((currentImage) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {!imagesRequested[currentImage.name] && <div>loading...</div>}

          <img
            style={{ opacity: imagesRequested[currentImage.name] ? 1 : 0 }}
            src={currentImage.src}
            onLoad={() => {
              setTimeout(() => { // Fake server latency (2 seconds for per image)
                setImagesRequested((previousState) => ({
                  ...previousState,
                  [currentImage.name]: true
                }));
              }, 2000);
            }}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to possibly create a LoadableImage component which will then handle onLoad event for an  object. This onLoad event can then call a parent callback function to set its loaded status.

LoadableImage.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

const LoadableImage = (props) => {
  const { src, alt, width, height, onLoad, onError, id } = props;

  //you can use this to render a custom broken image of some sort
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);

  const onLoadHandler = () => {
    if (typeof onLoad === "function") {
      onLoad(id);
    }
  };

  const onErrorHandler = () => {
    setHasError(true);
    if (typeof onError === "function") {
      onError(id);
    }
  };

  return (
    <img
      src={src}
      alt={alt}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      onLoad={onLoadHandler}
      onError={onErrorHandler}
    />
  );
};

export default LoadableImage;
```

now you can handle the callbacks in your implementation and act appropriately. You can keep state of all your images, and their loading status.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState(imageList);

  const imagesLoading = images.some((img) => img.hasLoaded === false);

  const handleImageLoaded = (id) => {
    setImages((prevState) => {
      const index = prevState.findIndex((img) => img.id === id);
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const newImage = { ...newState[index] };
      newImage.hasLoaded = true;
      newState[index] = newImage;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {imagesLoading && <h2>Images are loading!</h2>}
      {images.map((img) => (
        <LoadableImage
          key={img.id}
          id={img.id}
          src={img.src}
          onLoad={handleImageLoaded}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here handleImageLoaded will update the hasLoaded property of an image in the images state array when a image is loaded. You can then conditionally render your loading screen while (in this case) imagesLoading is true, as I have conditionally rended the "Imags are loading" text.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kepler-whn32?file=/src/App.js)

imageList looks like this

```
const imageList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516912481808-3406841bd33c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=683&q=80",
    hasLoaded: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    hasLoaded: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/151",
    hasLoaded: false
  }
];
```